# Converting a python list into numpy.ndarray recursively

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

A weird issue I have encountered today. Would appreciate an explanation for that behavior of `np.array`:

```
l1 = np.array([[1], [1]])
type(l1)
Out[43]: numpy.ndarray
l2 = np.array([[1, 2], [1]])
type(l2)
Out[44]: numpy.ndarray
```

**But:**

```
type(l1[0])
Out[45]: numpy.ndarray
type(l2[0])
Out[47]: list
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is due to the fact that both (or all, to be precise) elements are not in the same dimension.

Consider:

```
l1 = np.array([[1], [1, 2]])
print(type(l1[0]))
l2 = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 2]])
print(type(l2[0]))
```

Will output the (now) expected

```
<class 'list'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

In order to get `numpy.ndarray` "all the way down" all elements (and nested elements) must have the same dimension.

Comment: I have learnt something new today. Actually, this makes sense since otherwise the operator ```reshape``` will not be well defined. Thank you.